# Google's platform.js is giving a 307 redirect

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client

Yesterday I added `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js` to my scripts. I was able to use the `gapi` etc. Now, after 0 changes, trying to access `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js` gives a `307` from my actual domain (hosted on AWS) or localhost.

I can go to `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js` directly. Is it blocking my domain and localhost? Simply added it like `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I closed all Chrome instances and somehow this resolved the issue.